# Алгоритм быстрой вставки и поиска по индексу

Tags: java

Ищу алгоритм вставки и поиска по индексу работающий за O(1), есть ли готовые реализации на java? Если готовых реализаций нет, то можно просто название алгоритма?

Comment: чем вам не угодил классический ArrayList?

Comment: @etki в `ArrayList` вставка не за `O(1)`.

Comment: да правильно, вставка  в ArrayList происходит за время   O(n), есть ли какие-нибудь варианты?

Comment: @Suvitruf по индексу-то не за О(1)?

Comment: Если вас пугает worst case с ресайзом - просто прогнозируйте размер заранее и создавайте уже с нужным размером и получайте всё тот же O(1)

Comment: @etki эх такое себе решение если честно, но я думаю лучше все равно нету

Comment: @etki ещё про сдвиг элементов не забудьте.

Comment: "такое себе решение если честно, но я думаю лучше все равно нету" Вся жизнь Алексея Навального.

Comment: Какие то несовместимые вещи требуете. Если вставка в произвольное место по индексу со сложностью О(1), значит элементы должны иметь ссылки на соседние. Но в таком случае, что бы найти элемент, нужно проходить по ссылкам. Ускорить поиск можно, если заранее есть сведения об хранящихся данных, например, они отсортированы, или можно задать функцию хеширования, что бы класть в бакеты и пересчитывать все это дело при добавлении новых элементов. В общем - нужна конкретика.

Comment: я выслушал вас господа , скорее всего поступлю так , как посоветовал @etki